# Find the number of ways in which RESONANCE can be arranged so that letters R,S,O,A appear in the order same as in the word RESONANCE

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Find the number of ways in which RESONANCE can be arranged so that letters R,S,O,A appear in the order same as in the word RESONANCE

**My working:**

R
EE
S
O
NN
A
C

The number of such ways should simply be 4! divided by the total permutations i.e. =$\frac{9!}{2!2!4!}=3780$

But the answer is supposed to be $3870$ and I can't figure out why.

Comment: maybe a typo in the notes?

Comment: I think ur answer is right

Comment: @Alex I don't know...it was an mcq with both these options, and the one I ticked was wrong. Though I haven't really encountered any errors in the answers till now, maybe it's just a mistake like you said :)

Comment: Agreed. $9!/(2!^24!)$ is undoubtedly correct. It is easy to confuse those two numbers due to the transposition of 8 and 7. Do make sure *you* are reading everything correctly, although I suspect you are and it is *their* mistake.